# receber duas casas depois da virgula

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Preciso receber um valor em dinheiro e estou recebendo apenas uma casa depois da virgula.
exemplo 75.50 recebo 7.5
e 7 eu preciso receber 7.00;

estou usando Jquery;

Comment: De que forma você "recebe"? De uma consulta? Do formulário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar o [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), um método dos números, que faz duas coisas:

- fixa a quantidade de digitos na parte decimal
- transforma um numero em *string* para os zeros se manterem

```js
console.log((7.5).toFixed(2)); // dá 7.50
console.log((7).toFixed(2)); // dá 7.00
console.log((7.204).toFixed(2)); // dá 7.20
```

---

**Nota**: Se a quantidade de casas decimais após o ponto for superior ao informado, arredonda o valor, sendo [0...4] arredondado para baixo e [5...9] arredondado para cima.

Comment: Acrescentei uma nota sobre quando o valor excede o valor de casas decimais, nem sei se ficou bom rs, mas achei interessante acrescentar, caso queira alterar ou reverter não tem problema :)

Comment: @MarceloBoni ótimo, obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado! @Sergio

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma é utilizando o método toPrecision, que permite definir quantos dígitos no total (incluindo os digitos à esquerda e à direita do ponto decimal)  devem ser exibidos.

```js
var num = 7;

var result = num.toPrecision(3);

document.write (result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use esse plugin o jQuery Mask para mascara de todo o tipo.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário amigo, usei jquery mask em outro projeto, mas nesse não foi possível, por que na entrada (input) eram números inteiros e no calculo havia números reais, muitas vezes o resultado é um numero real.